# IF condition inside the repeater control?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, repeater

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox1" runat="server" Text="1" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox2" runat="server" Text="2" />
```

I have two checkbox, Based up on the Selection i need to run query and bind into repeater control.

In Repeater Control:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
<HeaderTemplate >
<table class="list_table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><%=CheckBox1.Checked ? Eval("1") : "" %></td> 
 <td><%=CheckBox2.Checked ? Eval("2") : "" %></td> 

    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

AVD suggestion i have changed my coding, if condition is working fine, but i need to bind the data from database into the repeater control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try,

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%=CheckBox1.Checked ? "1" : "" %></td>
        <td><%=CheckBox2.Checked ? "2" : "" %></td>
   </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

EDIT:

@Prince Antony G : If I select checkbox1 then run the query- select 1 from table1; or if I select checkbox2 then run the query- select 2 from table2; and bind the data into my repeater control (and both these tables have different fields)

You can't bound different data source to a *DataControl* because some of the binding expression (columns) are not available(found) in *either* of that case.

Page1.aspx markup

---

```
<div>
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <!--Bind the result from first table -->
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:View>

    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <!--Bind the result from second table -->
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</div>
```

Page1.aspx.cs - code behind

---

```
protected void BindResult(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox check = sender as CheckBox;
    switch (check.Text)
    {
        case "1": 
            /* 
                * 1. Execute - Select * from Table1
                * 2. Bind the DataSource to Repeater1
                */
            /* Shows the first View*/
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            break;
        case "2":
            /* 
                * 1. Execute - Select * from Table2
                * 2. Bind the DataSource to Repeater2
                */
            /* Shows the second View*/
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 condition is checked and it is displayed as 1 if if checkbox 1 is true, but i have to bind the data from databese into the repeater?

Comment: running two queries, for example: if i select checkbox1 then run the query- select 1 from table1; or if i select checkbox2 then run the query- select 2 from table2; and bind the data into my repeater control.

Comment: datatype is same only, that doesnot matter, i need to display into repeater

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15646/discussion-between-prince-antony-g-and-avd)